# Use a loop to select multiple records from a table to fill unbound text boxes in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table with the following fields:

```
StudentID
ClassID
TestID 
TestScore
```

For each unique combination of student and class, there MAY be up to 10 test IDs and corresponding test scores.  I have a form with 10 unbound text boxes which correspond to test scores for the 10 test IDs.  I'm trying to use the form to both EDIT and ADD data to my table (StudentScores).  Since its possible for a student to miss a class, each student-class combo may not necessarily have 10 records in the table.

I would like to be able to use a loop in an event procedure to retrieve the test scores from the table, based on a chosen Student and Class ID, to input into the text boxes.  The text boxes are named textbox1 through textbox10, corresponding to the 10 TestIDs.

Through searches on forums like this, I've been able to come up with the following code to pull data from  the 10 unbound text boxes to add as new records to the table:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("StudentScores", dbOpenTable)
For i = 1 To 10
rst.AddNew
rst![StudentID] = Me.StudentCombo1
rst![ClassID] = Me.ClassCombo1
rst![TestID] = i
If Not IsNull(Controls("Textbox" & i)) Then
   rst![TestScore] = CLng(Controls("Textbox" & i))
End If
rst.Update
Next
```

Ok, so the following code seems to work at least initially.  The issue I had originally was due to a typo.  However, when I change the value of the combo box and re-run the routine, I get an error that the recordset is empty.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
mmySQL = "SELECT * from StudentScores where ClassID =" & Me.ClassCombo1 & "AND StudentID =" & Me.StudentCombo1
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mmySQL)
rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    Controls("Textbox" & rst![TestID]) = rst![TestScore]
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: Get rid of spaces in field names, you will thank yourself later. Look at the crosstab query wizard. Come back with where you are stuck.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question.  Hopefully this will add clarity.

Comment: Are ClassID and StudentID both numeric, or do they have a data type of Text?

Comment: Your recordset should retrieve the 10 (or less) records for the studentID/classID and then loop through the records one-by-one and write to the appropraite textbox based on TestID. Something using rst.movefirst,  Do Until rst.eof, moveNext should do what you want. You seem to be pretty close.

Comment: Matt, please see my update.  Can you help me with the error I'm having?

Comment: Chris... both numeric

Comment: Ok, I found out why it wasn't working and am embarrassed to say it was just a typo.  I edited the post to show my current issue, which is that the code works on the initial run, however, on the next run, I get an error that the recordset is empty.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) There's an error in your `mmySQL` assignment - there needs to be a space before the AND added, i.e. `Me.ClassCombo1 & " AND StudentID ="`; 2) don't call `MoveFirst` given the record cursor will be at the first record (if any) anyhow; 3) don't bother calling `Close` or explicitly set object references to `Nothing` if you are at the end of a sub routine anyway - if Access didn't do this automatically, then it would be a serious bug giving rise to the question of whether any of it could be trusted.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston re: *"don't bother calling Close or explicitly set object references to Nothing"* - Sorry, but that is bad advice. In a VBA/VB6 environment it is **always** good practice to explicitly `Close` Recordsets, Connections, Files, etc., and it is **always** good practice to set Objects to `Nothing` when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Chris, thanks for catching the space error in the mmysql assignment. Its been a day of stupid mistakes. As far as items 2 and 3 goes, I did copy those parts from recommendations from another site. And they shared the same views as Gord does.

Comment: I do have a NEW issue, which I'd like to add to this thread.  The code above works to loop through the text boxes and add records to the table.  I was going to do the same thing to EDIT records - just changing rst.addnew to rst.edit, however, I now realize that this will only edit records that already exist in the table and will not ADD new records if they are missing (due to blanks from the original add).  So can someone tell me what would be the best way to handle this?  I could always delete existing records and then add them as new ones, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: @GordThompson - I completely disagree. Given VBA doesn't support weak references, every single object assignment involves an implicit AddRef call against the assigned object's IUnknown implementation; if Release isn't getting called on a non-nil object variable when the sub-routine exists, then rationally you should be doubting that AddRef was called in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting to the meat of the question, a few observations:

1. Currently you allow `Null` test scores in the StudentScores table. I'd be tempted to disallow them (i.e., set the field's Required property to `True`), though you know your data. That said, the code below assumes nulls aren't allowed.
2. Even in small forms I'd avoid using default control names like `TextBox1` - a common Access convention is to use a three letter prefix (e.g. `txtTestScore1`). Also, why `ClassCombo1` and `StudentCombo1` if there's only one of each? I'll stick to your current naming below for clarity however.
3. Your description refers to adding or editing, yet your text boxes to records code only covers the former... though I see you've now remarked on that yourself.
4. For this sort of thing you can use pure DAO or a bit of inline SQL. Until the amount of data gets a certain size (and 10 test scores is nowhere near that) it doesn't really matter which method you chose, however I'm going to plump for the second.
5. If you haven't already, you might want to put a validation rule on the `TestID` field to enforce a value between 1 and 10.

So, first a couple of constants - declare them at the top of the form module:

```
Const MaxTextScoreCount = 10 
Const TestScoreTextBoxPrefix = "TextBox"
```

Next, a method to clear existing values on the form:

```
Sub ClearTestScoreTextBoxes()
  Dim I As Integer
  For I = 1 To MaxTextScoreCount
    Me.Controls(TestScoreTextBoxPrefix & I).Value = Null
  Next I
End Sub
```

Third, a helper function to build a WHERE clause from the combo boxes:

```
Function BuildWhereClause() As String
  BuildWhereClause = " WHERE StudentID = " & StudentCombo1.Value & _
    " AND ClassID = " & ClassCombo1.Value 
End Function
```

Fourth, a method to populate the text boxes with the selection:

```
Sub UpdateTestScoreTextBoxes()
  Dim RS AS DAO.Recordset, SQL As String
  SQL = "SELECT TestID, TestScore FROM StudentScores" + BuildWhereClause
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbForwardOnly)
  ClearTestScoreTextBoxes
  While Not RS.EOF
    Me.Controls(TestScoreTextBoxPrefix & RS!TestID).Value = RS!TestScore
    RS.MoveNext
  Wend
End Sub
```

Fifth, a method to update the database from the text boxes:

```
Sub UpdateDatabase()
  Dim DB AS DAO.Database, I As Integer, Score As Variant, WhereClause as String, SQL As String
  Set DB = CurrentDb
  For I = 1 To MaxTextScoreCount
    Score = Me.Controls(TestScoreTextBoxPrefix & I).Value
    WhereClause = BuildWhereClause + " AND TestID = " & I
    If IsNull(Score) Then
      SQL = "DELETE FROM StudentScores" + WhereClause
    ElseIf DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT 1 FROM StudentScores" + WhereClause).EOF Then
      SQL = "INSERT INTO StudentScores(StudentID, ClassID, TestID, TestScore) " + _
            "VALUES (" & StudentCombo1.Value & "," & ClassCombo1.Value & "," & _
             I & "," & Score & ")"
    Else
      SQL = "UPDATE StudentScores SET TestScore = " & Score & WhereClause
    End If
    DB.Execute SQL
  Next I
End Sub
```

Should do it...

Comment: Chris, thank you very much for your response.  I was able to modify some other code that I found and was able to move on.  Nevertheless, your solution seems very elegant and I intend to try it once I have more time.  Again, thank you.